# It can be proven that $4^{2000} + 4^x + 4^{2023}$ is the square of an integer for exactly 3 integer values of x. What is the largest such value of x

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

> It can be proven that $4^{2000} + 4^x + 4^{2023}$ is the square of an integer for exactly 3 integer values of $x$. What is the largest such value of $x$?

This is a problem from a high school mathematics competition. I factored out $4^{2000}$ from the expression to turn the expression into $(1 + 4^{x-2000} + 4^{23})4^{2000}$, which is only a perfect square if $1 + 4^{x-2000} + 4^{23}$ is a perfect square, but I am not sure what I could do from there to determine for what values of $x$ that expression is a perfect square

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806330/find-all-x-such-that-427410004x-is-a-perfect-square), or similar posts at MSE. See also [here](https://kunduz.com/questions-and-answers/6-it-can-be-proven-that-the-trinomial-42000-4-42023-is-the-square-of-an-integer-for-exactly-3-values-of-x-what-is-the-largest-such-value-118482/).

Comment: @Rattus How are you making sense of $4^{x-2000}$? Can you prove that $x$ is at least $2000$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there are exactly three integer values of $x$ for which $4^{2000} + 4^x + 4^{2023}$ is a square integer, the largest such value is $x = 2045$. You can work this out by noticing that the given expression can be written as $(2^{2000})^2+(2^x)^2 + (2^{2023})^2$ and so you can try combinations for which this is a perfect square $(a + b)^2$. Working out what $x$ can be then comes down to matching up the non-squared term, so $(2^x + 2^{2023})^2$ gives $x = 1976$, $(2^{2000} + 2^{2023})^2$ gives $x = 2012$, and finally $(2^x + 2^{2000})^2$ gives $x = 2045$.

Comment: Great explanation. I didn't even think about rewriting the left-hand side of the equation as a perfect square. Thank you